# How do I uninstall rapache?

Tags: r, uninstallation, rapache

I want to uninstall rapache, make uninstall doesn't seem to do anything and a look at the rapache documentation and a google search turns up nothing. Any help would be great

Comment: added 'r' tag to hopefully attract more attention from the R experts. Good luck to you.

Comment: Did you build from source or use a package manager to obtain rapache?

Comment: Hi Alan, I am also trying to install Rapacke on CentOs,but I am facing some problems. How can I install Rapache on my system? Do i need to install other software? If yes then from where and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jeff said, find mod_R.so and delete it.  You will also want to remove any RApache directives that you added to configuration files.  I use a separate file, /etc/apache2/conf.d/rapache.conf, so I can just delete or comment out that file.  Finally of course, you restart/reload apache2 (sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart).

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the file mod_R.so from /usr/lib/apache2/modules, if you're on ubuntu and using the supplied apache2 package. Otherwise you'll have to hunt for the modules directory where you installed apache.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Use [a2dismod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/a2enmod.8.html) to disable an Apache module. Than you can delete the files and restart the server.

```
a2dismod(r)
```